# How to rename the indexes of a series structure in pandas from labels => 0,1,2,3....?

Tags: python, pandas

I know one way to pass index to the elements in the series,

```
names = ['India','Germany','Japan','America']
my_series = pd.Series(['Cricket','Football','Baseball','Basketball'], index = names)
```

**Output**:

```
India         Cricket
Germany      Football
Japan        Baseball
America    Basketball
dtype: object
```

But if i were to first define my series just by passing the elements,

```
my_series = pd.Series(['Cricket','Football','Baseball','Basketball'])
```

**Output:**

```
0       Cricket
1      Football
2      Baseball
3    Basketball
dtype: object
```

Now if i want to rename the rows from 0,1,2,3 to the names of the countries mentioned before, how should i do it??

Comment: `my_series.index = names`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `index` by list but it working only if same length of Series and list:

```
names = ['India','Germany','Japan','America']
my_series = pd.Series(['Cricket','Football','Baseball','Basketball'])

my_series.index = names
print (my_series)
India         Cricket
Germany      Football
Japan        Baseball
America    Basketball
dtype: object
```

If possible different lengths is possible use `rename` for avoid error by dictionary created by `enumerate`:

```
names = ['India','Germany','Japan']
my_series = pd.Series(['Cricket','Football','Baseball','Basketball'])

d = dict(enumerate(names))

my_series = my_series.rename(d)
print (my_series)
India         Cricket
Germany      Football
Japan        Baseball
3          Basketball
dtype: object
```

---

```
names = ['India','Germany','Japan','America', 'Spain']
my_series = pd.Series(['Cricket','Football','Baseball','Basketball'])

d = dict(enumerate(names))

my_series = my_series.rename(d)
print (my_series)
India         Cricket
Germany      Football
Japan        Baseball
America    Basketball
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use 
the public instance attribute [`pd.Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html)

```
my_series.index = names
print(my_series)
```

**Output**

```
India         Cricket
Germany      Football
Japan        Baseball
America    Basketball
dtype: object
```

if we couldn't use this you would have to do

```
pd.Series(my_series.values, index=names)
```

what would be inefficient

You can rename some index values ​​using

```
my_dict = dict(zip(my_series.index, names))
my_series = my_series.rename(my_dict)
```

note that this works not only when the index is `RangeIndex` 0, 1, 2, 3 ...